# Is there any eay to strict whereHas method in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

`whereHas` method in Laravel uses `EXISTS` from MySQL. The problem is that when for example brand and text specified it takes all the items with or without brand where text exists... But I need that when brand specified it would take only those with brand and text.
    $parts = AutoPart\Part::has('classifier')->with(['details', 'classifier', 'order', 'place'])->orderBy('id', 'desc');

```
if ($brand = $request->get('brand', FALSE)) {
    $parts->whereHas('details', function($query) use($brand) {
        $query->where('brand', '=', $brand);
    });
}

if ($model = $request->get('model', FALSE)) {
    $parts->whereHas('details', function($query) use($model) {
        $query->where('model', '=', $model);
    });
}

if ($text = $request->get('text', FALSE)) {
    if (strlen($text) > 0) {
        $parts->whereHas('details', function($query) use($text) {
            $query->where('notes', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%');
        });

        $parts->orWhereHas('classifier', function($query) use($text) {
            $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the the last condition to

```
 if ($text = $request->get('text', FALSE)) {
    if (strlen($text) > 0) {

       // This will put a bracket around the whereHas and the OrWherehas
       $parts->where(function($q) use($text) {
           $q->whereHas('details', function($query) use($text) {
               $query->where('notes', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%');
           });

           $q->orWhereHas('classifier', function($query) use($text) {
               $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $text . '%');
           });
       });

   }
}
```

hope it helps